# Некорректная работа Ifdef elif

Tags: c++, visual-c++, препроцессор

Коллеги, добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, почему у меня не выполняется условие elif?

```
#include <iostream>
#define debug

int main()
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "DEBUG";
#elif debug
    std::cout << "debug"; // Не выполняется
#else 
    std::cout << "else"; // А вот что выполняется в этом случае
#endif

}
```

Comment: После `#elif` должно быть выражение.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно так:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "DEBUG";
#elif defined(debug)
    std::cout << "debug"; // Не выполняется
#else 
    std::cout << "else"; // А вот что выполняется в этом случае
#endif
```

Или, для единообразия:

```
#if defined(DEBUG)
    std::cout << "DEBUG";
#elif defined(debug)
    std::cout << "debug"; // Не выполняется
#else 
    std::cout << "else"; // А вот что выполняется в этом случае
#endif
```

Или так:

```
#define debug 1

int main()
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "DEBUG";
#elif debug
    std::cout << "debug"; // Не выполняется
#else 
    std::cout << "else"; // А вот что выполняется в этом случае
#endif

}
```

А просто `#if debug`, которое превращается в `#if` без ничего — вообще не должно компилироваться, по большому счету... VC++ его и не компилирует.

Comment: А что в нашем случае делает единичка, добавленная в define?

Comment: @SALUTE 0 = ложь ; не 0 = правда

Comment: Пока не понятно, для чего мы это делаем, это нужно использовать на elif? С Ifdef все прекрасно работает и без 0, 1

Comment: `#ifdef` — это то же, что и `#if defined`, по смыслу — "если такой символ определен". А `#elif` совсем другое. Это если выражение истинно. Попробуйте написать `#define  DEBUG` и `#if DEBUG` первой строчкой — что будет? Вот потому я и предложил как один из вариантов писать `#elif defined`.

Answer (score 3):

Что означают команды?

1. #ifdef DEBUG _ если определено выражение DEBUG
2. #elif debug  _ иначе, если debug  что эквивалентно: иначе, если debug  есть true, а у вас это выражение определено, но оно не
   означает какое то значение.
   Вам предлагают варианты:

`#define debug 1` означает что `debug есть число 1`, которое отлично от нуля, а значит в условиях,
воспринимается как истина. Или же изменение команды  препроцессора на `#elif defined(debug)` что означает:  иначе, если определено **выражение** debug.
А ваше выражение "С Ifdef все прекрасно работает и без 0, 1" абсолютно не понятно. Не просто работа важна, а важна правильная работа, соответствующая вашим желаниям и ожиданиям. А для этого вы должны дать подходящие команды, и никто кроме вас не знает что вы хотите, вот и предложили два разных варианта.